# Doesn't work django-admin.py startproject mysite

Tags: python, django

I want start a new django project, I use windows 10.
If I write to console

```
python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
```

return

```
1.10.3
```

but if I write

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

it opens

```
...\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe
from django.core import management

if __name__ == "__main__":
management.execute_from_command_line()
```

and I have path in Environmental Variable:
Programs\Python\Python35-32\

How I can do it?

Answer (score 5):

django-admin is a command defined in django. you should call.

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```